# Selecting Data on Google Sheets based on Two Dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a large Google sheet that contains the following columns:
APPOINTMENT SET BY, COMPANY NAME, APPOINTMENT WAS BOOK ON, TIMESTAMP and ACTION

What query, or method can I use to select ALL of the data where the date of Appointment Book on is 7 days of the current date? I want to split my data in to Weekly and Monthly.

I have no idea what way is best and need advise.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @Dan, we don't need to see your real data, just a bit of dummy data, to see the structure of your sheet, with an example of a result that you want.  It should be easy to give you the answer you need.